# What is the difference between Native and ShadowDom ViewEncapsulation?

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, angular7

In my current angular 7 application we are struggling with a component from a library, which requires some css ressources. We do not want to apply those ressources to all the rest of our application, but to one specific component, its children and grandchildren.

During our research we found these two interesting options:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

and:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
```

In consequence, they both seem to use the browser's shadow dom implementation.

What is the difference between those options?

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#members

Comment: @selemmn Thanks for the links, but the first one seems not to cover `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`. The second one on the other hand has no documentation for `ViewEncapsulation.Native` (it is mentioned, but without description).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been been baffling me days ago, then I realized that **they converge a little but not totally**. The dissimilarity in fact is about **[the newer version of shadowDOM (v1)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom)**. As you can see **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/3553977bd75c8e168f1d4bfa42b7f09c677f7cbf#diff-8d3ccfb044f98a30c1465151f72a5c30L85)** in angular's code source they added an other condition for the **`ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`**:

> **Here they share the same *return***

```
 case ViewEncapsulation.Native:
 case ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom:
      return new ShadowDomRenderer(this.eventManager, this.sharedStylesHost, element, type);
```

> **And then they check whether it is *ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom* or not *(else condition)***

```
     if (component.encapsulation === ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom) {
          this.shadowRoot = (hostEl as any).attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        } else {
          this.shadowRoot = (hostEl as any).createShadowRoot();
        }
```

Thus, **`ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`** is a step to add a support to **ShadowDOM V1**, and **maybe** deprecate the **`ViewEncapsulation.Native`** as described **[here:](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24718#issue-198378735)**

> *ViewEncapsulation.Shadow is added as a new API, rather than changing the behavior of the ViewEncapsulation.Native option, which could lead
>   to unexpected results for developers currently using the v0 API. This
>   should (eventually?) deprecate the ViewEncapsulation.Native option.*

Answer (score -1):

Angular uses ViewEncapsulation to limit styles and views to the component they have been mentioned in, I think you already know this.
Native doesn't have many details, what I do know is that it is selective for browsers, not all browsers actually acknowledge it.
For ShadowDom, Angular docs have an explanation but it's not too detailed, this extract clears up some parts though:

> "Note that the shadow DOM is not a new thing by any means — browsers have used it for a long time to encapsulate the inner structure of an element. Think for example of a  element, with the default browser controls exposed. All you see in the DOM is the  element, but it contains a series of buttons and other controls inside its shadow DOM. The shadow DOM spec has made it so that you are allowed to actually manipulate the shadow DOM of your own custom elements."
> See more here: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)